# Regex escape specific characters

Tags: php, regex, escaping, character

I'm using preg_split to make array with some values.
If I have value such as 'This*Value', preg_split will split the value to array('This', 'Value') because of the * in the value, but I want to split it to where I specified, not to the * from the value.How can escape the value, so symbols of the string not to take effect on the expression ?

Example:

```
// Cut into {$1:$2}
$str = "{Some:Value*Here}";
$result = preg_split("/[\{(.*)\:(.*)\}]+/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// Result:

Array(
    'Some',
    'Value',
    'Here'
);

// Results wanted:

Array(
    'Some',
    'Value*Here'
);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the string and what do you want to split it into?

Comment: Just don't use `*` in your split regex? Or do you mean you want to use `*` as a delimiter, but also allow it within the individual values inside the string?

Comment: Yes, Marc B.I want to split with *, but also use it in the value, without splitting values.

Comment: Please add example text.  From your example, we cannot tell the difference between a delimiter and a `*` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regular expression is a little... wild. Most special characters inside a character class are treated literally, so it can be greatly simplified:

```
$str = "{Some:Value*Here}";
$result = preg_split("/[{}:]+/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

And now `$result` looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => string(4) "Some"
  [1] => string(10) "Value*Here"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `[` and `]` are interpreted as character classes, so any character inside them matches.  Try this one, but don't split on it, use preg_match and look in the match's captured groups.

```
"/(\{([^:]*)\:([^:]*)\})+/"
```

Original answer (which does not apply to the OP's problem):

If you want to escape `*` in your values with `\` like `this\*value`, you can split on this regex:

```
(?<!\\)\*
```

Comment: This doesn't work..

Here is your code

`$str = '{test}:{asd}{asd}:{12*3}';
echo "<pre>";
preg_match("/(\{(.*)\}\:\{(.*)\})+/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";`

Result:
`Array
(
    [0] => {test}:{asd}{asd}:{12*3}
    [1] => {test}:{asd}{asd}:{12*3}
    [2] => test}:{asd}{asd
    [3] => 12*3
)
`

Answer (score 2):

The correct and safest solution to your problem is to use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote). If the string contains chars that shall not be quoted, you need to [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) them back after quoting.